# Help with SQL for Coldfusion query -- Getting back Counts, Totals or other Math

Tags: sql

I am drawing a blank on how best to go about this task.  I basically need to write some SQL for an Access db that will take data more or less in the following format:

```
State     Lost    Name
  NY       no      A
  NY       no      B
  NY       yes     C
  NY       no      D
  MD       yes     E
  MD       yes     F
  VA       no      G
  VA       yes     H
```

And I need a query to return the following:

```
 State     CountLost    Total in State
  NY          1             4
  MD          2             2
  VA          1             2
```

My current query works just fine in getting me the first two columns but I'm not quite sure how to append it to get this last column, showing the total in each state.
Either that or just as good would be State and a column for % lost per state:

```
State        %Lost in State
 NY              25%
 MD              100%
 VA              50%
```

Here's my current query getting me the first two columns.  Hopefully, someone can help me sort out the rest...

```
SELECT lkuState.StateName as state, Count(lkuState.StateName) AS statecount
FROM lkuState INNER JOIN .........
GROUP BY lkuState.StateName, tblMain.Lost
HAVING ((tblMain.Lost)=false)
```

Comment: There's really nothing germane to ColdFusion here, so I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most databases you could use a CASE statement (combined with SUM) to conditionally count the number Lost. But IIRC, Access does not support CASE and uses IIF instead.

```
SELECT s.StateName, COUNT(*) AS TotalInState, 
       SUM( IIF(m.Lost = 'yes', 1, 0) ) AS CountLost
FROM  tblMain m INNER JOIN lkuState s ON s.StateID = m.StateID
GROUP BY s.StateName
```

Comment: Thanks much.  But I've just realized that I have to address my issue differently as some parameters have changed... though I suspect your answer would work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Okay. If you have any more questions, just ask.